# Find and Replacing the data in text boxes with a macro in word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm currently trying to write a macro in word that loops through the document and updates all the years by 1 (So for example, from 2025 to 2026, etc.). Below is the macro I wrote to do so. However, I'm running into one problem: While the macro is essentially a relatively simple find and replace and works if I click the button on the home drop-down, the macro doesn't work that way. From googling, it seems as though it may be due to the fact that a lot of the data are in text boxes, which don't seem to be affected by the macro, which is odd considering the macro is emulating the find and replace function. Is there any way to write my macro to make it include the textboxes? I should note that there are over 8000 individual textboxes, so manipulating just one is unfortunately not possible.

```
For yr 9 to 0 Step -1

CY = CY + yr

With Selection.Find

.Text = CY

.Replacement.Text = CY + 1

.Forward = True

.Wrap = wdFindCountinue

End With

Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

CY = Year(Now)

Next yr
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to check the textboxes with an extra search.

I would split the code into two subs:

- one will do the replacement to the range passed to that sub
- the outer sub will do the replacement for the documents content and will then iterate over all textboxes - and pass the textboxes textrange to the replacement sub.

```vb
Sub replaceAll()

replaceYear ThisDocument.Content

Dim shp As Shape
For Each shp In ThisDocument.Shapes
    If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then
        If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then
            replaceYear shp.TextFrame.TextRange
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub


Private Sub replaceYear(rg As Word.Range)

Dim CY As Long, yr As Long
CY = Year(Now)

For yr = 9 To 0 Step -1

    CY = CY + yr
    
    With rg.Find
        .Text = CY
        .Replacement.Text = CY + 1
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With
    
    rg.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    
    CY = Year(Now)
Next yr
End Sub
```